# Find columns where at least one row contains an alphabetical letter

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following data set:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'A': [1, 2, 3],
         'B': ['one', 2, 3],
         'C': [4, 5, '6Y']
         })
```

I would like to find out - without any cumbersome for loop - which columns contain at least one case with an alphabetical letter (here: `B` and `C`). I guess the result should either be a list of booleans or indices.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a quick and simple solution, you can use `replace` and filter:

```
df.replace('(?i)[a-z]', '', regex=True).ne(df).any()

A    False
B     True
C     True
dtype: bool

df.columns[df.replace('(?i)[a-z]', '', regex=True).ne(df).any()]
# Index(['B', 'C'], dtype='object')
```

---

Another option is applying `str.contains` column-wise:

```
mask = df.astype(str).apply(
    lambda x: x.str.contains(r'[a-z]', flags=re.IGNORECASE)).any()
mask

A    False
B     True
C     True
dtype: bool

df.columns[mask]
# Index(['B', 'C'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: @00schneider if you'r wondering, add `$` to the regex pattern character class to handle that as well.

Comment: I actually like your second option and implemented that. Thank you, looks shorter than what I had in mind ;)

Comment: one more thing: What does `r` in `r'[a-z]'` exactly mean/do?

Comment: okay, I had some problems making your answer work. The bland reason? .astype(str) made `nan` out of `NaN`. However, I could not fix your code yet to make things work. My work around is to exclude all NaN beforehand, but I would appreciate a more elegant version :)

Comment: @00schneider not at my PC... give me a couple of hours and I'll get back to you.

Comment: I just tried it myself one more time by replacing the 3 in `df['A']`with `np.NaN`, which then produces A    True
B    True
C    True
dtype: bool

Comment: @00schneider NaN is mathematically defined to be not equal to itself (Nan != Nan is True).

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. Your function checks if any element of a column contains an alphabetical letter. It also returns True if an element is NaN because it is converted to nan by the function. That is what I was talking about in the comment from July 3rd.

Comment: @00schneider Sorry, I understood now. You need to disregard NaNs using an additional condition. Here is my suggestion: `(df.replace('(?i)[a-z]', '', regex=True).ne(df) & df.notna()).any()`

Comment: Wonderful, you helped me a ton! Could you edit your answer so future users are aware of this?

Answer (score 5):

We could use [`pd.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').isna().any().tolist()
# [False, True, True]
```

Comment: what if the case contains non-alphabetical symbols such as '$'?

Comment: So you would like those cases to be set to False? Does the first approach not work in such case? @00schneider

Comment: Both of your solutions result in `True` if '$' is in a column but I guess I can tinker that to fit to my needs. Thank you!

Comment: How can we use the True False list to filter the columns the dataframe?

Comment: @sagar https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing

Answer (score 3):

In that case you can do with `to_numeric`

```
df.apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce').isnull().any()
Out[37]: 
A    False
B     True
C     True
dtype: bool
```

---

Update

```
df.stack().str.contains('[a-zA-Z]').groupby(level=1).any()
Out[62]: 
A    False
B     True
C     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: what if the case contains non-alphabetical symbols such as '$'?

Comment: @00schneider in that case you need check the method cs95 provided